# the transaction should be unified in the application layer or the domain layer in DDD

Tags: java, mysql, domain-driven-design

The infrastructure layer has an existing implementation, that role is to update the object to the database.

```
public class Repository {
    public void update(AggregateRoot do, ValueObject value);
}
```

Should I choose transactional on ApplicationSerice layer

```
public class ApplicationSerice {
    @Transactional
    public void update(AggregateRoot do, ValueObject value) {
        repository.update(do, value);
    }
}
```

or transactional on DomainService layer

```
public class DomainService {
    @Transactional
    public void update(AggregateRoot do, ValueObject value) {
        repository.update(do, value);
    }
}

public class ApplicationSerice {
    public void update(AggregateRoot do, ValueObject value) {
        domainService.update(do, value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Should I choose transactional on ApplicationSerice layer

This is, I believe, the choice that is most consistent with the pattern as described by Eric Evans.  Application code is responsible for managing the transaction, and you will normally see the interactions with the repositories happening in the application layer rather than the domain layer.

See *Domain Driven Design; Tackling Complexity in the Heart of Software*, chapter 6.

Comment: I want to add: since only one aggregate should be modified per transaction and an aggregate is a transaction or consistency boundary an invocation of a domain command IS effectivly a single transaction. Nevertheless a technical transaction via annotation on the application service ensures that all data access to invoke the domain and save the result is consistent. Thus it makes sense to have the database transaction in this layer